# Converting String to char?

Tags: java, string, char

I need to take a String and then work out how many times each letter appears in the string. I thought of maybe converting each letter of the string into an individual char. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can use `toCharArray()`. And look at the String class to see which methods can help you to achieve what you want : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 3):

you can use this

```
myString.toCharArray();
```

to get a char[] out of it. Or just use this :

```
myString.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourStringVariable.toCharArray()`

`char[] array = yourStringVariable.toCharArray();`

Comment: Use a code block, it exists for _wrapping code_. Bold is not good for that.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout

`String#toCharArray()` method in [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) API. This method returns a `char[] array` with all characters in the String. *You can get each character from the array using the index*. say, char[i] to return the character of the string in index 'i'. *Please note that Array index starts from '0'*

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
   Integer count = counts.get(str.charAt(i));
   if (count == null) {
      count = 1;
   } else {
      count = count+1;
   }
   counts.put(str.charAt(i), count);
}
```

The end result is a map containing all of the characters within the string and a count of how many of each one was found.

Comment: The question is likely part of a homework assignment thus I'm not sure it's a good idea to give away the whole solution.